# AWS AppSync Null @connection query result

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm working to create a web app using Amplify, and would like to create a relationship between two tables to keep things DRY. I have 2 tables: `Listing` and `Service`. Each Listing should be related to one Service. My (abbreviated) schema looks like this. All queries / resolvers are auto-generated by `amplify push`

```
type Listing 
@model
@auth(rules: [{ allow: public, operations: [read] }])
{
  id: ID!
  status: Status
  source: String
  service: String
  serviceDetail: Service @connection (keyName: "service")
}

type Service @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  homepage: AWSURL
  logo: String
}
```

To eliminate any other issues, I'm running my tests in the AppSync Console.

Running the `ListServices` query returns all expected data from the `Service` table without any errors. Running a `getService` query on a specific `id` returns the expected data without any errors.

Running the `ListListings` query returns with no errors and all expected data from the `Listings` table. The `serviceDetail` field only contains `null`.

I've been digging through the documentation all morning, and can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

So, I defined the `@connection` wrong. The correct syntax is:

```
ServiceDetail: Service @connection (fields: ["service"])
```